# Unable to start Springboot 2.3.3 with apache camel 3.4.3 and Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel, swagger

I'm trying to migrate from camel 2.x to 3.x.
The goal is to create an API with Swagger documentation. I can run the application, but as soon as I add the swagger configuration I get this error:

```
2020-08-24 16:04:27.174  INFO 21736 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-24 16:04:27.176  INFO 21736 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.s.CamelHttpTransportServlet      : Destroyed CamelHttpTransportServlet[CamelServlet]
2020-08-24 16:04:27.195  INFO 21736 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-24 16:04:27.211 ERROR 21736 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route doc-api because of null
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:125) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:263) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:156) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.ja
r:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:114) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3
.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:2809) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2657) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2620) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.SpringBootCamelContext.doStart(SpringBootCamelContext.java:43) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2452) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:121) ~[camel-spring-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:157) ~[camel-spring-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-con
text-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-conte
xt-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-conte
xt-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEA
SE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEA
SE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELE
ASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.ja
r:5.2.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring
-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
        at se.capgemini.kafka.producer.service.KafkaProducerServiceApplication.main(KafkaProducerServiceApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such a
s the camel-openapi-java component)
        at org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException.wrapRuntimeCamelException(RuntimeCamelException.java:52) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:67) ~[camel-support-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:101) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.channel.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:143) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:87) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:154) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:78) ~[camel-support-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:334) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:184) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such as the camel-openapi-java component)
        at org.apache.camel.component.rest.RestApiEndpoint.createProducer(RestApiEndpoint.java:207) ~[camel-rest-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultEndpoint.createAsyncProducer(DefaultEndpoint.java:200) ~[camel-support-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:232) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:115) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:84) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:101) ~[camel-api-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1459) ~[camel-base-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60) ~[camel-support-3.4.3.jar:3.4.3]
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

My pom.xml looks like this:^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>se.capgemini</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-producer-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-producer-service</name>
    <description>Demo Spring Boot with Camel and Kafka Producer</description>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.4.3</camel.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-openapi-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-rest-swagger-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my rest configuration looks like this:

```
@Component
public class KafkaProducerAPI extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
                //.component("servlet")
                .contextPath("/kafka-producer-service")
                .port(8080)
                .apiContextPath("/")
                .apiProperty("api.title", "Test REST API")
                .apiProperty("api.version", "v1")
                .apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

        rest()
                .tag("Kafka Producer API")
                .consumes(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .produces(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                //.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .description("something")

                .get("/test")
                //.outType(Status.class)
                .route()
                .process(exchange -> {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello world!");
                })
                .end()
                .endRest();
    }
}
```

Probably I'm missing something simple, as I have a prety similar implementation with camel 2.x and it works just fine.

Comment: Try set .apiComponent("openapi") in your rest configuratoon

Comment: Also check that the generated WAR has in its classes META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/restapi folder with openapi file inside, thats the file Camel try to auto discover. Not sure if something is wrong with the WAR packaging

Answer (score 4):

I finally fixed it by adding the following:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-swagger-java</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Also the com.fasterxml.jackson.core 2.11.2 was giving problems so I had to downgrade to 2.10.5.

Thank you for the suggestions Claus Ibsen

Comment: Hi, I am struggling to make it working "Camel(3.8.0) + SpringBoot (2.4.2) + Swagger".
If you have a working example in GitHub, can you please share the link?

Comment: Sorry @CRSardar, but I don't have any project that I can share publicly. But let me know what problems you are facing and maybe I can help.